# How to connect to remote MongoDB with mongo-connector?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, mongo-collection

How can I connect to a MongoDB cluster on Mongo Atlas using `mongo-connector`?

I have tried to connector to my cluster with the following commands:

**First attempt**

`sudo mongo-connector -m "mongodb://g******:*********@rest-api-data-shard-00-00-xemv3.mongodb.net:27017,rest-api-data-shard-00-01-xemv3.mongodb.net:27017,rest-api-data-shard-00-02-xemv3.mongodb.net:27017/admin?ssl
=true&replicaSet=rest-api-data-shard-0&authSource=admin" -a g****** -p "***********" -t http://localhost:9200 -d elastic2_doc_manager`

**Response**:

`Logging to mongo-connector.log.
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongo_connector/util.py", line 90, in wrapped
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongo_connector/connector.py", line 263, in run
    main_conn['admin'].authenticate(self.auth_username, self.auth_key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 1018, in authenticate
    connect=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 434, in _cache_credentials
    raise OperationFailure('Another user is already authenticated '
OperationFailure: Another user is already authenticated to this database. You must logout first.`

**Second attempt**:

`sudo mongo-connector -m "mongodb://rest-api-data-shard-00-00-xemv3.mongodb.net:27017,rest-api-data-shard-00-01-xemv3.mongodb.net:27017,rest-api-data-shard-00-02-xemv3.mongodb.net:27017/admin?replicaSet=rest-api-data-shard-0" -a g********* -p "********" -t http://localhost:9200 -d elastic2_doc_manager`

**Response**:

`Logging to mongo-connector.log.
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongo_connector/util.py", line 90, in wrapped
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongo_connector/connector.py", line 263, in run
    main_conn['admin'].authenticate(self.auth_username, self.auth_key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 1018, in authenticate
    connect=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 439, in _cache_credentials
    writable_preferred_server_selector)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 210, in select_server
    address))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 186, in select_servers
    self._error_message(selector))
ServerSelectionTimeoutError: rest-api-data-shard-00-02-xemv3.mongodb.net:27017: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer,rest-api-data-shard-00-00-xemv3.mongodb.net:27017: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer,rest-api-data-shard-00-01-xemv3.mongodb.net:27017: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answered on the [github issue](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/issues/554). Solution:

> In your first attempt, the problem is that you are specifying the username and password for MongoDB twice. Remove the -a g****** -p "***********" and it should work fine. If you need to authenticate to Elasticsearch you need to use a mongo-connector config file and set the correct authentication options for the Python Elasticsearch client, eg:
>
> `{
>     "mainAddress": "mongodb://user:pass@mongodb:27017,mongodb:27018,mongodb:27019/admin?ssl=true&replicaSet=name&authSource=admin",
>     "verbosity": 1,
>     "docManagers": [
>       {
>         "docManager": "elastic2_doc_manager",
>         "targetURL": "http://localhost:9200",
>         "args": {
>           "clientOptions": {
>              "http_auth": ["user", "secret"],
>              "use_ssl": true
>           }
>         }
>       }
>     ]
>   }`
>
> In your second attempt, it looks like the problem is that you forgot to add ssl=true to the MongoDB connection string. That's why you're getting Connection reset by peer errors.